# CSS: how to change input type number background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

Im trying to change the arrows in the input type number:
background-color: 282930
arrows color: 666666
Only that but i was searching and i didn't find a way to do only that.
Image html and css example:
[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.number {
    background-color: #282930;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 50px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input class="number" type="number" value="42">
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, first get rid of the `input[type="number"]` CSS selectors as they are removing the spinner arrows. Next, please be much clearer as to what  your problem is and what you've tried. Where are these images coming from? What is the relationship between the number and the image?

Comment: The image is my complete code but i didnt upload because is not necessary. I need to remove the arrows background color. I'm realizing that in firefoxit looks different

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
html {
    color-scheme: dark !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know you can't change them using CSS but you can use buttons to replace them.

+I think chrome has some abilities in this case but it's not reliable.

Comment: okey, good to know, if so i will opt to make my own buttons

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).